# Equality sign with p on top, $\stackrel{p}{=}$

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

I saw this symbol, $\stackrel{p}{=}$, when referring to two distributions being equal, so I'm guessing it means equality in probability/distribution? A quick search didn't actually got me anywhere.

Comment: Always better to be more specific. Where did you see this? What was the full statement?

Comment: Maybe... See Olav Kallenberg, [Foundations of Modern Probability (Springer, 1997)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Foundations_of_Modern_Probability/uL7UBwAAQBAJ), page 25: "For any random elements ξ and η in a common measurable space, the equality $ξ \stackrel{d}{=} η$ means that ξ and η have the same *distribution*"